# ReactJS: Array passed to child as props from fetch API call return undefined

Tags: arrays, reactjs, fetch

I'm using an API that requires one call to get a list of search results, then one more call per result so I can get details from those results: a list of ingredients.

The functions seem to do what they're supposed to in the parent component, as using console.log returns the values that I expect, but when the child component receives these props, the array it gets is undefined.

I'm testing on local JSON files right now so the code I paste will reflect that and not an actual API endpoint.

This is the API call to return a list of results:

```
  fetchAPIData(input) {
    input = this.props.input;
    fetch('https://localhost:5001/testData.json')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        this.setState( { recipes: data.results, isLoading: false })
    })
  }
```

And this is what I have to get the details from the results:

```
  getIngredients(recipes) {
    var ingredients = [];
    recipes.map((recipe) => {
      fetch('https://localhost:5001/recipeDetails.json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        ingredients = ingredients.concat(data.extendedIngredients);
      })
    })
```

Because I want a complete list of ALL the ingredients in the search reults, I've made an array that concatenates the results. If I put `console.log(ingredients)` after concatenating, I will get an array with all the ingredients. However, when that gets passed to the child component:

`<RecipeFilter onHandleFilter={this.handleFilter} ingredients={this.getIngredients(this.state.recipes)} />`

The array it receives is undefined. From reading around I've been able to figure out that returning the array using something like `return ingredients;` won't work because fetch is an async function, so the values would be returned before the promises resolve and I'll end up with an empty array(which I tried anyway and yes, that's exactly what happened).

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can store ingredients in a state, may be with the name `ingredState` and pass it to RecipeFilter like `<RecipeFilter onHandleFilter={this.handleFilter} ingredients={this.getIngredients(this.state.recipes)} ingredStateProp = {this.state.ingredState} />`

In your getIngredients method you can set the state of newly made `ingredState` like below:

```
getIngredients(recipes) {
    var ingredients = [];
    recipes.map((recipe) => {
      fetch('https://localhost:5001/recipeDetails.json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        ingredients = ingredients.concat(data.extendedIngredients);
         this.setState({
           ingredState : ingredients
         })
      })
    }
```

)

Comment: @Arkfaidh Did the solution help you?

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick button besides the answer if it helped. Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I had tried setting the state before, and it causes a bunch of errors in the console as well as freezing the tab it's on. I don't think setState plays well with map()